# Same display between 2 monitors on Raspberry pi 4

Tags: pi-4, display

I want to know if its possible and what is the easiest way to setup both my monitors on a single Raspberry PI 4 to display the same view instead of a standard dual monitor setup where you can do some things on one monitor and other things on the other. For my application, both monitors must mirror each other.

Comment: If you're using PiOS with desktop with 2 'normal' screens (HDMI, DVI, VGA, etc): use screen configuration in preferences menu and drag the second on top of the first monitor and save the config

Comment: You are right. I was really unaware that you can do that but that works as expected. Thanks